# Are being (something) just yet VS. are not (something) yet

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

In English, there are many ways to express an idea but the **context** is still the same. Let's say you are playing DOTA(an online game), and the shoutcaster has just said this:

> "player A and player B are a bit low on damage between the two of them, because **neither one are being** "level 6"(strong) **just yet**."(from the shoutcaster)

Vs.

> "player A and player B are a bit low on damage between the two of them, because **neither one of them aren't** "level 6"(strong) **yet**"(I constructed this one)

Are the two sentences the same as for the context?

Comment: Why are you considering "are being"?  What's the difference to you between "are being" and just "are"?  We don't normally use *to be* in the progressive.

Comment: @stangdon OP considers "are being" because it's the phrase used by someone commenting the game. Maybe that one isn't a native speaker either.

Comment: I strongly believe he is a native one. I have added ''being'' as that's what he said. Here's the link: https://youtu.be/ylKBHSf4V1A between 2:05-2:30mins.

Comment: @JohnArvin - Thanks!  I listened to the video, and he says, "...low on damage between the two of them, **neither one of them being** level 6 just yet."  That's a slightly different structure: it's a [participial phrase](https://www.paperrater.com/page/participial-phrase), whereas after *because* you need a separate clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not the same. Yours does not mean what you intend.

You have included an unnecessary double negation. The word **neither** does include a negation.

According to Cambridge Dictionary
[**neither**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/neither)

> **not** either of two things or people

---

Your phrase rewritten using that dictionary:

> **not** either of them are **not** level 6

That sentence implies that **they are in level 6** and I think that this is not your intention.

I think that this is correct and says what you mean:

> because neither one of them are level 6 yet

Comment: **”Because any of the two is not level 6 yet**'' -Is this ok now?

Comment: I doesn't sound natural to me but I'm no English native speaker. As I have pointed you just have to remove the not from your initial "aren't"

Comment: @JohnArvin Negatives should go earlier in the sentence; we like to make a statement negative as early as possible. "Neither of them are level 6" is much better than "Both of them are not level 6", which is unnatural and a bit harder to follow to a native speaker's ear.

Comment: @Drazex, very useful, sagacious tip there hehe. But can I add an extra to this... ''*Neither of them are level 6* **yet**" -is that ok?

Comment: @JohnArvin Yes, adding a "yet" is perfect. The only difference is that "yet" tells us that we expect that it *will* happen in the future, which sounds like exactly the case in this example.